# How can I use SVG code as a source for <img src={...} /> element?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I was using svg code directly in a React component:

```
export const AdventurerToken = (props) => {
    return (
        <div style={props.style}>
            <svg width="3vw" height="3vw" viewBox="0 0 99 119">
                <metadata>
                    Created by potrace 1.15, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017
                </metadata>
                <g transform="translate(0.000000,119.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
                   fill={props.color} stroke="none">
                    <path d="M336 1174 c-10 -9 -16 -33 -16 -62 0 -26 -4 -52 -8 -59 -4 -6 -35 -17 -69 -23 -35 -7 -68 -19 -74 -26 -23 -28 50 -108 134 -145 20 -9 27 -19 27
-40 0 -23 -5 -30 -27 -35 -98 -21 -212 -74 -265 -122 -36 -32 -38 -38 -38 -92 0 -84 11 -92 134 -105 32 -3 62 -8 67 -11 11 -6 -12 -69 -50 -133 -77 -129
-114 -215 -115 -266 l-1 -50 168 -3 168 -2 57 90 c33 52 63 89 71 88 8 -2 35 -41 61 -88 l47 -85 172 -3 171 -2 0 43 c0 56 -35 151 -90 247 -86 149 -86 148
-74 160 6 6 43 14 83 17 98 8 121 26 121 97 0 62 -17 89 -84 133 -42 28 -157 74 -221 88 -29 6 -28 7 23 24 79 27 122 76 122 139 0 47 -72 102 -135 102 -18
0 -25 7 -30 33 -3 17 -13 49 -22 70 l-16 37 -138 0 c-112 0 -141 -3 -153 -16z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    )
};
```

However Firefox doesn't accept "vw" units in sve width and height properties. Workaround would be using the svg as a source for an image element:

```
export const AdventurerToken = (props) => {
    const color = props.color;
    const adventurerSVG =
        <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 99 119">
            <metadata>
                Created by potrace 1.15, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017
            </metadata>
            <g transform="translate(0.000000,119.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill={color} stroke="none">
                <path d="M336 1174 c-10 -9 -16 -33 -16 -62 0 -26 -4 -52 -8 -59 -4 -6 -35 -17 -69 -23 -35 -7 -68 -19 -74 -26 -23 -28 50 -108 134 -145 20 -9 27 -19 27
-40 0 -23 -5 -30 -27 -35 -98 -21 -212 -74 -265 -122 -36 -32 -38 -38 -38 -92 0 -84 11 -92 134 -105 32 -3 62 -8 67 -11 11 -6 -12 -69 -50 -133 -77 -129
-114 -215 -115 -266 l-1 -50 168 -3 168 -2 57 90 c33 52 63 89 71 88 8 -2 35 -41 61 -88 l47 -85 172 -3 171 -2 0 43 c0 56 -35 151 -90 247 -86 149 -86 148
-74 160 6 6 43 14 83 17 98 8 121 26 121 97 0 62 -17 89 -84 133 -42 28 -157 74 -221 88 -29 6 -28 7 23 24 79 27 122 76 122 139 0 47 -72 102 -135 102 -18
0 -25 7 -30 33 -3 17 -13 49 -22 70 l-16 37 -138 0 c-112 0 -141 -3 -153 -16z"/>
            </g>
        </svg>

    return (
        <img style={{width: "10vw"}} src={adventurerSVG}/>
    )
};
```

This does not work, as evidenced by https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-fire-m560j?file=/src/App.js - direct import works, import as a source of  element does not. What am I doing wrong? Why is the image not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: use `<div>` instead of `<img>`.
Put svg code in a variable with 100% width and height, put variable inside  with correct width / height:

```
export const AdventurerToken = (props) => {
    const color = props.color;
    const adventurerSVG =
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 99 119">
            <metadata>
                Created by potrace 1.15, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017
            </metadata>
            <g transform="translate(0.000000,119.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill={color} stroke="none">
                <path d="M336 1174 c-10 -9 -16 -33 -16 -62 0 -26 -4 -52 -8 -59 -4 -6 -35 -17 -69 -23 -35 -7 -68 -19 -74 -26 -23 -28 50 -108 134 -145 20 -9 27 -19 27
-40 0 -23 -5 -30 -27 -35 -98 -21 -212 -74 -265 -122 -36 -32 -38 -38 -38 -92 0 -84 11 -92 134 -105 32 -3 62 -8 67 -11 11 -6 -12 -69 -50 -133 -77 -129
-114 -215 -115 -266 l-1 -50 168 -3 168 -2 57 90 c33 52 63 89 71 88 8 -2 35 -41 61 -88 l47 -85 172 -3 171 -2 0 43 c0 56 -35 151 -90 247 -86 149 -86 148
-74 160 6 6 43 14 83 17 98 8 121 26 121 97 0 62 -17 89 -84 133 -42 28 -157 74 -221 88 -29 6 -28 7 23 24 79 27 122 76 122 139 0 47 -72 102 -135 102 -18
0 -25 7 -30 33 -3 17 -13 49 -22 70 l-16 37 -138 0 c-112 0 -141 -3 -153 -16z"/>
            </g>
        </svg>

    return (
        <div style={{width: "3vw"}}>
            {adventurerSVG}
        </div>
    )
};
```

Works both in Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code

1. the SVG is not valid for use as an image because it's missing the SVG namespace declaration i.e. xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
2. you need to give the img element a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), not just a Node

So a working example looks like this...

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {adventurerSVG}
      <img src={'data:image/svg+xml,' + ReactDOMServer.renderToString(adventurerSVG)}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const adventurerSVG = (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 99 119">
    <metadata>
      Created by potrace 1.15, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017
    </metadata>
    <g
      transform="translate(0.000000,119.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
      fill="red"
      stroke="none"
    >
      <path
        d="M336 1174 c-10 -9 -16 -33 -16 -62 0 -26 -4 -52 -8 -59 -4 -6 -35 -17 -69 -23 -35 -7 -68 -19 -74 -26 -23 -28 50 -108 134 -145 20 -9 27 -19 27
-40 0 -23 -5 -30 -27 -35 -98 -21 -212 -74 -265 -122 -36 -32 -38 -38 -38 -92 0 -84 11 -92 134 -105 32 -3 62 -8 67 -11 11 -6 -12 -69 -50 -133 -77 -129
-114 -215 -115 -266 l-1 -50 168 -3 168 -2 57 90 c33 52 63 89 71 88 8 -2 35 -41 61 -88 l47 -85 172 -3 171 -2 0 43 c0 56 -35 151 -90 247 -86 149 -86 148
-74 160 6 6 43 14 83 17 98 8 121 26 121 97 0 62 -17 89 -84 133 -42 28 -157 74 -221 88 -29 6 -28 7 23 24 79 27 122 76 122 139 0 47 -72 102 -135 102 -18
0 -25 7 -30 33 -3 17 -13 49 -22 70 l-16 37 -138 0 c-112 0 -141 -3 -153 -16z"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
);
```